# How to pass an ExecutionContext to spray route or better to avoid ask and use tell

Tags: scala, akka, spray

As I am gathering experiences with Spray.io I see that there is more ways how to solve the task. I found a various opinions which were sometimes contradictory. So I would like to ask more experienced users to share their view.
Essentially having a REST api and separated services layer all assembled via cake pattern as follows:

```
object Main extends App with BootedCore with ServiceActors with RestApi with Web
```

ServiceActors are holding an ActorRefs to various services and RestApi holds Spray-routes. Service actors replies with case classes.

The question is how to connect those two layers?

** Possibility 1 - Use akka ask pattern**

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  //TODO: Excecution context - this is not scalable
  val adServiceRoute: Route = {
    path("service" / "import" / "status") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`text/plain`) {
          complete {
            adImporterService.ask(GetImportStatus)(1 second).mapTo[StatusOfImport]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  implicit val importStatusMarshaller: Marshaller[StatusOfImport] =
    Marshaller.of[StatusOfImport](ContentTypes.`text/plain`) { (value, contentType, ctx) =>
      val string = "Hello marshalled status"
      ctx.marshalTo(HttpEntity(contentType, string))
    }
```

I have found some Cons to this solution which I would like to get clarified. 
- various blogs clams that ask pattern is best to avoid if possible, some example reasoning: e.g. it hides underlying errors etc.
- not sure on which ExcecutionContext to run. Import global is definitively the correct one. What I have available is ActorSystem. Is it common to configure separated dispatcher just for this purpose?

**Possibility 2 - use tell**
I tried to rewrite the previous one but wasn't able to make it work

```
 val adServiceRoute: Route = {
    path("service" / "ad" / "import" / "status") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`text/plain`) (getServiceStatus)
      }
    }
  }

  implicit val importStatusMarshaller: Marshaller[StatusOfImport] =
    Marshaller.of[StatusOfImport](ContentTypes.`text/plain`) { (value, contentType, ctx) =>
      val string = "Hello marshalled status"
      ctx.marshalTo(HttpEntity(contentType, string))
    }

  def getServiceStatus(ctx: RequestContext): Unit = {
        adImporterService.tell(GetImportStatus , ctx.responder)
  }
```

The issue here is that adImporterService's response is StatusOfImport which responder doesn't know how to handle. Creating an actor-per-request just for handling the response in order to transform it to HttpResponse seems to me as overkill.

I am clearly missing something important here. 
Could someone more experienced clarify ?

Comment: Did you import your implicit marshaller `importStatusMarshaller'  in your service. Then u can simply use,  ctx.complete(status)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have? Did the code work?

Creating one actor per request is really not an issue. Actually, when you use the the ask pattern that is precisely what you are doing, you create an actor implicitly.

Actors should be considered a "plentiful" resource... If you don't do this, it means you are handling the request synchronously. If that could be a problem to your application is up to you, but usually creating one actor per request is precisely what you want, so you can handle as many simultaneous requests as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use spray's [`onComplete`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/) directive. For example:

```
onComplete(adImporterService.ask(GetImportStatus).mapTo[StatusOfImport]) {
  case Success(v) => complete(v)
  case Failure(e) => ...
}
```